# ADF table rowspanning

Tags: java, html, oracle, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I have a scenario where I would like to like to rowspan the adf table columns. Below is the snapshot of the use case for ADF [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the pivotTable component
http://jdevadf.oracle.com/adf-richclient-demo/faces/components/pivotTable.jspx

Comment: thanks for the useful resource provided. I need a favour from you. In your demo, the grouped items are always coming in the first column as the pivot table wizard ask for the for the first column items. Is there any provision for the grouped items to move in 2nd or 3rd column as shown in my screenshot?

Comment: Also I need a provision to export this table as pdf.

Comment: With a pivot table you can't have the break on the second column. If this is what you want try this - https://blogs.oracle.com/groundside/entry/break_group_formatting_in_a